# btrfs size issue

Tags: linux, btrfs, snapshot

According to my calculations, my `btrfs` should have a total size of 153 GB by totalling the Exclusive component from `btrfs qgroup show`, but it actually shows up as around 700 GB using other disk usage commands. Can anyone give me some guidance as to how to identify actual disk space usage of the various subvolumes and snapshots?

`btrfs qgroup show --raw /`

```
Qgroupid    Referenced    Exclusive   Path 
--------    ----------    ---------   ---- 
0/5              16384        16384   <toplevel>
0/256      43656376320     24752128   @
0/257     199570546688     58773504   @home
0/258        141635584    139149312   @log
0/259      19789303808  19789303808   @pkg
0/260            65536        65536   @.snapshots
0/261            16384        16384   @/var/lib/portables
0/262            16384        16384   @/var/lib/machines
0/263            16384        16384   @/config
0/264            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots
0/524            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/260/snapshot
0/531            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/267/snapshot
0/543            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/279/snapshot
0/553            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/289/snapshot
0/554            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/290/snapshot
0/555            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/291/snapshot
0/556            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/292/snapshot
0/557            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/293/snapshot
0/558            16384        16384   @/.snapshots
0/559            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/294/snapshot
0/561            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/295/snapshot
0/563            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/296/snapshot
0/565            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/297/snapshot
0/568            77824        77824   @home/.snapshots
0/570            16384        16384   @/config/.snapshots/298/snapshot
0/571     394465181696     94642176   @home/.snapshots/1/snapshot
0/577     394902482944    522248192   @home/.snapshots/2/snapshot
0/597      44380700672  28607815680   @.snapshots/1/snapshot
0/1198    403471388672   7393017856   @home/.snapshots/313/snapshot
0/1199     43513024512  16787304448   @.snapshots/302/snapshot
0/2016    420993523712   9901699072   @home/.snapshots/722/snapshot
0/2017     41414443008   4527894528   @.snapshots/711/snapshot
0/2750    448229560320  12392017920   @home/.snapshots/1089/snapshot
0/2751     33841131520   6639910912   @.snapshots/1078/snapshot
0/3180     17179885568  17179885568   @/@swap
0/3697    257331318784  11361894400   @home/.snapshots/1547/snapshot
0/3698     42040500224   1002987520   @.snapshots/1536/snapshot
0/4121    197541814272   2328797184   @home/.snapshots/1746/snapshot
0/4122     42637578240    832200704   @.snapshots/1735/snapshot
0/4141    197536718848   1549631488   @home/.snapshots/1755/snapshot
0/4142     43396767744     44879872   @.snapshots/1744/snapshot
0/4181    197592567808   1761644544   @home/.snapshots/1773/snapshot
0/4182     43398729728     35799040   @.snapshots/1762/snapshot
0/4209    197790572544   1257037824   @home/.snapshots/1786/snapshot
0/4210     43392077824    131264512   @.snapshots/1775/snapshot
0/4261    197735538688   1545723904   @home/.snapshots/1811/snapshot
0/4262     43364900864    109977600   @.snapshots/1800/snapshot
0/4315    199007887360   2477486080   @home/.snapshots/1836/snapshot
0/4316     43392901120     60137472   @.snapshots/1825/snapshot
0/4365    199153360896    499658752   @home/.snapshots/1858/snapshot
0/4366     43373875200      3051520   @.snapshots/1847/snapshot
0/4381    199269126144    611155968   @home/.snapshots/1866/snapshot
0/4382     43373932544      3043328   @.snapshots/1855/snapshot
0/4429    199583887360    651161600   @home/.snapshots/1889/snapshot
0/4430     43374006272     26869760   @.snapshots/1878/snapshot
0/4517    199715659776    443428864   @home/.snapshots/1931/snapshot
0/4518     43463548928      2854912   @.snapshots/1920/snapshot
0/4521    199673978880    341987328   @home/.snapshots/1933/snapshot
0/4522     43463548928      1445888   @.snapshots/1922/snapshot
0/4525    199664271360    359690240   @home/.snapshots/1935/snapshot
0/4526     43463548928      1429504   @.snapshots/1924/snapshot
0/4529    199657545728    348688384   @home/.snapshots/1937/snapshot
0/4530     43463548928      2117632   @.snapshots/1926/snapshot
0/4533    199663243264    359550976   @home/.snapshots/1939/snapshot
0/4534     43464167424      5672960   @.snapshots/1928/snapshot
0/4537    199661416448    338726912   @home/.snapshots/1941/snapshot
0/4538     43464171520      3645440   @.snapshots/1930/snapshot
0/4541    199676805120    346292224   @home/.snapshots/1943/snapshot
0/4542     43464192000      5369856   @.snapshots/1932/snapshot
0/4545    199558840320     67620864   @home/.snapshots/1944/snapshot
0/4546     43656331264     28667904   @.snapshots/1933/snapshot
0/4549    199553486848      2633728   @home/.snapshots/1946/snapshot
0/4550     43656351744      4964352   @.snapshots/1935/snapshot
0/4551    199553486848        81920   @home/.snapshots/1947/snapshot
0/4552     43656368128       212992   @.snapshots/1936/snapshot
0/4553    199553486848        49152   @home/.snapshots/1948/snapshot
0/4554     43656368128       131072   @.snapshots/1937/snapshot
```

Totalling the `Referenced` column gives 7897677631488 (7.9TB) and the exclusive columns adds up to 153471860736 (153GB), neither of which come close to the actual reported disk usage of the 1TB drive.

`df -h` reports 716G used and 212G available.

`btrfs fi df -h /`

```
Data, single: total=690.00GiB, used=687.40GiB
System, DUP: total=32.00MiB, used=112.00KiB
Metadata, DUP: total=16.00GiB, used=13.59GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

I only have one directory in home and to avoid counting the `/home/.snapshots` directory, I just ran the following on my home directory:
`btrfs fi du -s /home/user`

```
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
 200.01GiB    13.20MiB   184.65GiB  /home/user
```

which, if you squint at it enough, reaches nearly to the Referenced value of 199570546688 of `@home` in the `qgroups` output above, and also close to the 203G reported by `du -shc /home/user`.

### Things I have already tried

I have already run the following clean up commands and waited for completion:

- `btrfs check` (booted from USB stick and then executed on the device)
- `btrfs scrub /` on the mounted root during normal operations, and
- `btrfs balance /`
- `btrfs quota disable /`
- `btrfs quota enable /` in case the quotas are misreporting.

None of them had an appreciable difference on the totals.

Many thanks in anticipation!

Comment: What do you mean by "actual usage"? Perhaps even answering that question could give some insight into a solution.

Comment: Actual usage is the actual space consumed on the disk. I've edited the question to reflect this. A snapshot will not take up the full amount of space as it shares common data with earlier snapshots.

Comment: Non BTRFS tools are inaccurate using BTRFS. Some non BTRFS tools like `lsblk`, `df`, `du`, `blkid` and etc. have been improved in later program versions to fix the issues. Distributions like openSUSE and SUSE Linux Enterprise have fixed standard non BTRFS tools. If you still use old program versions, they might tell you nonsense. You can believe what the btrfs tools tell you, `btrfs filesystem df /` and etc....

Comment: @paladin thanks, except that all of the commands I used (except one) were `btrfs` commands. However, they are not giving consistent results.

Comment: You should read how BTRFS snapshots work. Usually older snapshots are read-only and only the latest "snapshot", the current in use filesystem is read/write. Older snapshots have older states of data, which has their own size. So your error is that you are calculating wrong. Try to summarize the `Exclusive` rows.

Comment: @paladin I thought I did. See above: " and the exclusive columns adds up to 153471860736 (153GB)"

Comment: `btrfs fi df -h /` tells you the disk space needed for the mounted filesystem in `/` and all of its subvolumes. `df -h` seems to match this. `btrfs qgroup show --raw /` tells you that from these 716GB, about 153GB are used exclusive for qgroups. Not everything is in a qgroup.

Comment: So basically, the qgroup stats to identify snapshot sizes aren't reliable.

Comment: Qgroups and snapshots are something different.